Issue with the loading.tsx file in Next.js
I want to implement loading ui in my app by adding loading.tsx files to route segments:
File system.
But the problem is that when I add the loading.tsx file to the /jobs and /jobs/[id] route segments and navigate to the /jobs/[id] route from the /jobs route, I get almost infinite page loading.
I tried to find out the reason of such behavior and I saw in the network tab of the browser console a large number of identical requests from the client to the server:
Network tab.
When I remove the loading.tsx file everything is fine. The client makes only one-two requests to the server and the page loads. Why is this happening and how can I solve this issue?
Here is a code of the /jobs/[id] route:
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const allJobs = await prisma.job.findMany({ select: { id: true } });
  return allJobs.map(({ id }) => ({ id }));
}

interface Props {
  params: { id: string };
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params: { id } }: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const job = await cachedFetchJobById(id);

  if (!job) {
    notFound();
  }

  return {
    title: job.title,
  };
}

export default async function Page({ params: { id } }: Props) {
  const job = await cachedFetchJobById(id);

  if (!job) {
    notFound();
  }

  return (
    <main className='main'>
      <Breadcrumbs items={[{ label: 'jobs', href: '/jobs' }, { label: job.title }]} />
      <JobDetails {...job} />
    </main>
  );
}


I'm pretty much a beginner with Next.js but I have a solution proposal but it may fail. At least you can try. So, from my understanding loading.js file wraps your page.js and layout.js kind of visual components within a React Suspense component. But this React Suspense element is rendered inside your patent layout.js or template.js file. So, when you add a loading.js file inside a route segment which doesn't have a layout/template.js you try to render your page.js component with it in your parent layout/template.js file but this doesn't work that way.

What you can try is to add a layout.js or template.js in your route segment /jobs and your loading.js inside the same route segment. This may work as you intend it to be.

I tried to add layout.tsx and loading.tsx directly inside the /jobs route but it behaves the same way. Problem is still exist. To many requests when I navigate to the /jobs/[id] route. Interesting that it happens only when I navigate to the /jobs/[id] by clicking a link. If I initially load app from /jobs/[id] everything works fine.
